# Spring-boot behind dedicated Tomcat behind Apache2 proxy?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm running a `apache2` reverse proxy that sends the request to a *dedicated* `tomcat8`  on `localhost:8080`

For proper self-reference within my applications, I need to forward the https headers accordingly. Therefor the proxy is configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.myapp.org
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ... (SSL directives omitted for readability)
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the spring advise is to set the following application.properties in case of running an *embedded* tomcat behind an proxy:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for 
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-prot
```

Problem: as I'm running a dedicated tomcat, any `server.*` properties are ignored.

Question: how can I achieve the same configuration for the dedicated tomcat?